# Question closed - Why?

Tags: discussion

My question was closed before it got an answer, and I really could use an answer.
This was the question link:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/41014/html-carousel-with-youtube-videos-stop-roatation-until-end-of-video

Could someone explain why this is? It has really set me back and I could use some help.

Answer (score 2):

It was closed because coding questions are off topic for this website. Normally we migrate them to StackOverflow but I'm fairly certain they will close it since they typically don't like question where you are asking *how* to do something without showing what you tried first. If you update your question to show an attempt to answer your own questions we can then migrate there for you.

Comment: Thank you John, it would be nice if this would be said when a question is closed. I a new to this so I did not know that WebMasters was not for code. I just assumed. My apologies. I posted the same question on StackOverflow a week prior posting it to WebMasters. I am still getting used to how this all works. Thanks for the assistance! I edited my question on StackOverflow to hopefully be a little more helpful.